# Create new dataframe by groups based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't have much experience with working with pandas. I have a pandas dataframe as shown below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : [1,2,1],
                'start' : [1,3,4],
                'stop' : [3,4,8]})
```

I would like to create a new dataframe that iterates through the rows and appends to resulting dataframe. For example, from row 1 of the input dataframe -  Generate a sequence of numbers [1,2,3] and corresponding column to named 1

```
A    seq
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    3
2    4
1    4
1    5
1    6
1    7
1    8
```

So far, I've managed to identify what function to use to iterate through the rows of the pandas dataframe.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Can you possible re-phrase your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would want to use loops.

```
In [1164]: data = []

In [1165]: for _, x in df.iterrows():
      ...:     data += [[x.A, y] for y in range(x.start, x.stop+1)]
      ...:

In [1166]: pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'seq'])
Out[1166]:
   A  seq
0  1    1
1  1    2
2  1    3
3  2    3
4  2    4
5  1    4
6  1    5
7  1    6
8  1    7
9  1    8
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way with apply:

```
(df.set_index('A')
   .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.arange(x['start'], x['stop'] + 1)), axis=1)
   .stack()
   .to_frame('seq')
   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
   .astype('int')
)
Out: 
   seq
A     
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    3
2    4
1    4
1    5
1    6
1    7
1    8
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers above, here's a method that defines a function for interpreting the dataframe input shown, into a form that the poster wants:

```
def gen_df_permutations(perm_def_df):
    m_list = []
    for i in perm_def_df.index:
        row = perm_def_df.loc[i]
        for n in range(row.start, row.stop+1):
            r_list = [row.A,n] 
            m_list.append(r_list)
    return m_list
```

Call it, referencing the specification dataframe:

```
gen_df_permutations(df)
```

Or optionally call it wrapped in a dataframe creation function to return a final dataframe output:

```
pd.DataFrame(gen_df_permutations(df),columns=['A','seq'])


    A   seq
0   1   1
1   1   2
2   1   3
3   2   3
4   2   4
5   1   4
6   1   5
7   1   6
8   1   7
9   1   8
```

N.B. the first column there is the dataframe index that can be removed/ignored as requirements allow.